# How to save Amazon keys in database if keys are correct?

Tags: php, api, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm learning the Amazon S3 PHP API, and I want to save my Amazon keys if these are valid for login into an Amazon account or alert the user if he puts wrong keys via the following code:

```
$awsaccesskey = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$awssecretkey = 'xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx';

$s3_object = new S3($awsaccesskey, $awssecretkey );
```

Now, how can I check whether theses keys are valid or invalid and save them in a database if correct, e.g.:

```
if('keys valid')
{
    //save in database
}
else
{
    // entered keys are invalid, plz check your keys
}
```

Does the object return any error if keys is valid or invalid?

I don't know how get an authentication response, could someone please suggest a solution for it? Thank You.

Comment: when i put wrong keys it returns output:`S3 Object ( )` and put right key and `print_r($s3);` its again returns `S3 Object ( )` then how trace key validation with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may try this

```
$s3 = new S3('aws_access_key', 'aws_secret_key');

$return = @$s3->putBucket('mybucket');
if($return)
{
   echo 'valid keys';
   //now you can save key in your db
   //delete created bucket
   $s3->deleteBucket('mybucket');
 }
 else
 {
   echo "You entered invalid Amazon access credentials";
 }
```

Comment: the official PHP API functions are little different: create_bucket() and delete_bucket() and to test for true if($return->status == 200). Otherwise works for me +1